# Java multi-thread file server and client

Tags: java, multithreading, homework, socket, network-file-transfer

My task was to build a multi-thread file server and a client that can upload or download a named file over sockets.  It is assumed that the client will finish after its operation and there is no need to supply a file list from the server (although I plan to add that). There is no error check if the client enters a file name that does not exist on the server.

I think that the basic protocol I've set up is ugly at best and would like opinions on a better way to approach this.

I'm quite sure this is barely doing the job, so criticism is welcomed.

Flow:

- Start Server
- Start Client, connection made if possible.
- Client then chooses whether to upload or download a file.
- Server receives this initial message and takes appropriate action.

**`FileServer`**

```
public class FileServer {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
            System.out.println("Server started.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Port already in use.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + clientSocket);

                Thread t = new Thread(new CLIENTConnection(clientSocket));

                t.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error in connection attempt.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`CLIENTConnection`**

```
public class CLIENTConnection implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader in = null;

    public CLIENTConnection(Socket client) {
        this.clientSocket = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String clientSelection;
            while ((clientSelection = in.readLine()) != null) {
                switch (clientSelection) {
                    case "1":
                        receiveFile();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        String outGoingFileName;
                        while ((outGoingFileName = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            sendFile(outGoingFileName);
                        }

                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Incorrect command received.");
                        break;
                }
                in.close();
                break;
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void receiveFile() {
        try {
            int bytesRead;

            DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

            String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_client_" + fileName));
            long size = clientData.readLong();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                size -= bytesRead;
            }

            output.close();
            clientData.close();

            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" received from client.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Client error. Connection closed.");
        }
    }

    public void sendFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            //handle file read
            File myFile = new File(fileName);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            //bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            //handle file send over socket
            OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

            //Sending file name and file size to the server
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
            dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
            dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            dos.flush();
            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" sent to client.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("File does not exist!");
        } 
    }
}
```

**`FileClient`**

```
public class FileClient {

    private static Socket sock;
    private static String fileName;
    private static BufferedReader stdin;
    private static PrintStream os;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            sock = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot connect to the server, try again later.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        os = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

        try {
              switch (Integer.parseInt(selectAction())) {
            case 1:
                os.println("1");
                sendFile();
                break;
            case 2:
                os.println("2");
                System.err.print("Enter file name: ");
                fileName = stdin.readLine();
                os.println(fileName);
                receiveFile(fileName);
                break;
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("not valid input");
        }


        sock.close();
    }

    public static String selectAction() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("1. Send file.");
        System.out.println("2. Recieve file.");
        System.out.print("\nMake selection: ");

        return stdin.readLine();
    }

    public static void sendFile() {
        try {
            System.err.print("Enter file name: ");
            fileName = stdin.readLine();

            File myFile = new File(fileName);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            //bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

            //Sending file name and file size to the server
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
            dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
            dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            dos.flush();
            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" sent to Server.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("File does not exist!");
        }
    }

    public static void receiveFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            int bytesRead;
            InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();

            DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);

            fileName = clientData.readUTF();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_server_" + fileName));
            long size = clientData.readLong();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                size -= bytesRead;
            }

            output.close();
            in.close();

            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" received from Server.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic client / server code looks pretty good.

If you want clearer vision for "something" in java, you need to start defining the boundary of that "something".  In Java the ideal choice is the Class.

Start by refactoring your code to separate what you consider the "Protocol" into a "Protocol" class.  Later on, if you find that you want to support more than one "Protocol" write a second "ProtocolTwo" class, rename the "Protocol" class to something like "ProtocolOne" and make a common shared interface between the two called "Protocol".

My imaginings for a "Protocol" class that would work with your code:

```
Protocol protocol = new Protocol();
Action action = protocol.readAction(sock.getOutputStream());
action.perform();
```

Of course, it is homework, so you'll get the joy of putting all the important bits into the right places.  Good luck, and post back as you get closer to the goal.

Comment: cheers. With exams looming it is time to refocus my attention. I'll revisit the code after. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @chrisloughnane Fully understand, and good luck (though luck has nothing to do with it) on your exams!