# Java multithreaded file server and client - emulate TCP over UDP

Tags: java, multithreading, homework, network-file-transfer

My task was similar to [my last assignment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20961/java-multi-thread-file-server-and-client/) but this time I had to do it with UDP instead of TCP. This basically means I had to `emulate TCP over UDP`.

Multithreading was an interesting problem as I had to simulate [TCP's 3-way handshake](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml).

I decided to use encapsulation and break up the file I'm transferring into 512 byte size blocks, except for the last block which is more likely going to be smaller. I then create my message object with the correct `segmentID` and a `bytesToWrite`. The `bytesToWrite` is needed to handle the last block, there is a better way to do this. I just got lazy here. I'll fix that when I have time.

Every segment received is acknowledged, after a 2x second timeout if there is no ACK then the segment is resent. In the event an ACK fails to get through the receiver will get a segment ID that is exactly -1 to the expected ID. In this way I know an ACK has failed and I resend it.

This has been tested locally using the built in fail simulator (2% chance a packet fails) and tested in the wild by asking a friend set the server up in London, England and I downloaded a 14.4mb file to my machine in Galway, Ireland. It took a long time and had 35 failed packets, 19 of which were failed ACKs.

Both the `Server` and `Client` use the `UDPFileReceiver` and `UDPFileSender` classes.

**`Server`**

```
/*****
 * CT326 - Assignment 12 - c.loughnane1@nuigalway.ie - 09101916
 */
package pkg12;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server
{
    private static int clientID = 1;
    private static DatagramSocket serverSocket;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Server started.");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

        /**
         * ASSIGNMENT INSTRUCTION The server should be multi-threaded, and
         * have one thread per connection.
         */
        serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(8550);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                DatagramPacket packet =  new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length );
                serverSocket.receive(packet);
                System.out.println("SERVER: Accepted connection.");
                System.out.println("SERVER: received"+new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength()));

                //new socket created with random port for thread
                DatagramSocket threadSocket = new DatagramSocket();

                Thread t = new Thread(new CLIENTConnection(threadSocket, packet, clientID++));

                t.start();

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Error in connection attempt.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`CLIENTConnection` thread class**

```
/*****
 * CT326 - Assignment 12 - c.loughnane1@nuigalway.ie - 09101916
 */
package pkg12;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author c.loughnane1@nuigalway.ie - 09101916
 */
public class CLIENTConnection implements Runnable
{

    private int clientID;
    private byte[] buffer;
    private int bytesToReceive;
    private DatagramSocket clientSocket;
    private DatagramPacket packet, initPacket;
    private String userInput, filename, initString;

    public CLIENTConnection(DatagramSocket clientSocket, DatagramPacket packet, int clientID) throws IOException
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.packet = packet;
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            buffer = new byte[618];

            System.out.println("THREAD: " + new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength()));

            initString = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

            StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(initString);

            userInput = t.nextToken();
            filename = t.nextToken();
            if (t.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                bytesToReceive = new Integer(t.nextToken()).intValue();
            }

            switch (messageType.valueOf(userInput))
            {
                case put:
                    //sends a message gets the new port information to the client
                    send(packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort(), ("OK").getBytes());

                    //create Object to handle incoming file
                    new UDPFileReceiver(clientSocket);

                    break;
                case get:
                    File theFile = new File(filename);

                    send(packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort(), ("OK").getBytes());

                    //create object to handle out going file
                    UDPFileSender fileHandler = new UDPFileSender(clientSocket, packet);
                    fileHandler.sendFile(theFile);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Incorrect command received.");
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("*** Transfer for client " + clientID + " complete. ***");
    }

    private void send(InetAddress recv, int port, byte[] message) throws IOException
    {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, recv, port);
        clientSocket.send(packet);
    }

    private void send(byte[] message) throws IOException
    {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
        clientSocket.send(packet);
    }

    public enum messageType
    {
        get, put;
    }
}
```

**`Message` class**

```
/*****
 * CT326 - Assignment 12 - c.loughnane1@nuigalway.ie - 09101916
 */
package pkg12;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Message implements Serializable {

    private int segmentID;
    private byte[] packet;
    private int bytesToWrite;

    public Message(){}

    public Message(int segmentID, byte[] packet, int bytesToWrite) {
        this.segmentID = segmentID;
        this.packet = packet;
        this.bytesToWrite = bytesToWrite;
    }

    public int getBytesToWrite() {
        return bytesToWrite;
    }

    public int getSegmentID() {
        return segmentID;
    }

    public byte[] getPacket() {
        return packet;
    }
}
```

**`Client`**

```
/*****
 * CT326 - Assignment 12 - c.loughnane1@nuigalway.ie - 09101916
 */
package pkg12;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 *
 * @author c.loughnane1@nuigalway.ie - 09101916
 */
public class Client
{

    private static byte[] buffer;
    private static int port = 8550;
    private static DatagramSocket socket;
    private static BufferedReader stdin;
    private static StringTokenizer userInput;
    private static DatagramPacket initPacket, packet;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

        buffer = new byte[618];

        stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String selectedAction = selectAction();
        userInput = new StringTokenizer(selectedAction);

        try
        {
            switch (messageType.valueOf(userInput.nextToken()))
            {
                case put:
                    packet = new DatagramPacket((selectedAction).getBytes(), (selectedAction).getBytes().length, address, port);
                    socket.send(packet);

                    File theFile = new File(userInput.nextToken());

                    initPacket = receivePacket();

                    //create object to handle out going file
                    UDPFileSender fileHandler = new UDPFileSender(socket, initPacket);
                    fileHandler.sendFile(theFile);
                    break;


                case get:
                    packet = new DatagramPacket((selectedAction).getBytes(), (selectedAction).getBytes().length, address, 8550);
                    socket.send(packet);

                    initPacket = receivePacket();

                    socket.send(initPacket);

                    //create Object to handle incoming file
                    new UDPFileReceiver(socket);
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("not valid input");
        }

        socket.close();
    }

    private static DatagramPacket receivePacket() throws IOException
    {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        return packet;
    }

    public static String selectAction() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("COMMANDS: get *filename*");
        System.out.println("\t  put *filename*");
        System.out.println("\t  example: put data.txt");
        System.out.print("ftp> ");

        return stdin.readLine();
    }

    public enum messageType
    {
        get, put;
    }
}
```

**`UDPFileSender`**

```
/*****
 * CT326 - Assignment 12 - c.loughnane1@nuigalway.ie - 09101916
 */
package pkg12;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class UDPFileSender
{
    private int segmentID;
    private int reSendCount;
    private byte[] msg, buffer;
    private FileInputStream fileReader;
    private DatagramSocket datagramSocket;
    private int fileLength, currentPos, bytesRead;
    private final int packetOverhead = 106; // packet overhead

    public UDPFileSender(DatagramSocket socket, DatagramPacket initPacket) throws IOException
    {
        msg = new byte[512];
        buffer = new byte[512];
        datagramSocket = socket;

        //setup DatagramSocket with correct Inetaddress and port of receiver
        datagramSocket.connect(initPacket.getAddress(), initPacket.getPort());
        segmentID = 0;
    }

    public void sendFile(File theFile) throws IOException
    {
        fileReader = new FileInputStream(theFile);
        fileLength = fileReader.available();

        System.out.println("*** Filename: " + theFile.getName() + " ***");
        System.out.println("*** Bytes to send: " + fileLength + " ***");

        send((theFile.getName() + "::" + fileLength).getBytes());

        DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        datagramSocket.receive(reply);

        //waits for receiver to indicate OK to send
        if (new String(reply.getData(), 0, reply.getLength()).equals("OK"))
        {
            System.out.println("*** Got OK from receiver - sending the file ***");

            //outer while to control when send operation comlete
            //inner while to control ACK messages from receiver
            while (currentPos < fileLength)
            {
                bytesRead = fileReader.read(msg);

                Message message = new Message(segmentID, msg, bytesRead);
                System.out.println("Sending segment " + message.getSegmentID() + " with " + bytesRead + " byte payload.");
                byte[] test = serialize(message);

                send(test, bytesRead + packetOverhead);

                currentPos = currentPos + bytesRead;

                //handle ACK of sent message object, timeout of 2 seconds. If segementID ACK is not received
                //resend segment.
                datagramSocket.setSoTimeout(2000);
                boolean receiveACK = false;
                while (!receiveACK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        datagramSocket.receive(reply);
                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
                    {
                        send(test, bytesRead + packetOverhead);
                        System.out.println("*** Sending segment " + message.getSegmentID() + " with " + bytesRead + " payload again. ***");
                        reSendCount++;
                    }
                    if (new String(reply.getData(), 0, reply.getLength()).equals(Integer.toString(message.getSegmentID())))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Received ACK to segment" + new String(reply.getData(), 0, reply.getLength()));
                        segmentID++;
                        receiveACK = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("*** File transfer complete...");
            System.out.println(reSendCount + " segments had to be resent. ***");
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Recieved something other than OK... exiting");
        }
    }

    private void send(byte[] message, int length) throws IOException
    {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, length);
        datagramSocket.send(packet);
    }

    private void send(byte[] message) throws IOException
    {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
        datagramSocket.send(packet);
    }

    public byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
        objectStream.writeObject(obj);
        objectStream.flush();
        return byteStream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

**`UDPFileReceiver`**

```
/*****
 * CT326 - Assignment 12 - c.loughnane1@nuigalway.ie - 09101916
 */
package pkg12;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UDPFileReceiver
{
    private byte[] buffer;
    private Message receiveMSG;
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private String filename, initString;
    private FileOutputStream fileWriter;
    private DatagramPacket initPacket, receivedPacket;
    private int bytesReceived, bytesToReceive, simulateBadConnection, expectedSegmentID;
    private final boolean simulateMessageFail = false;//true if you want to simulate a bad connection

    public UDPFileReceiver(DatagramSocket socket) throws IOException
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        buffer = new byte[618];  //618 is the size of my message object. 512 payload, 106 overhead

        System.out.println("*** Ready to receive file on port: " + socket.getLocalPort() + " ***");

        initPacket = receivePacket();
        initString = "Recieved-" + new String(initPacket.getData(), 0, initPacket.getLength());

        //get the file name and byte size of file name
        StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(initString, "::");
        filename = t.nextToken();
        bytesToReceive = new Integer(t.nextToken()).intValue();

        System.out.println("*** The file will be saved as: " + filename + " ***");
        System.out.println("*** Expecting to receive: " + bytesToReceive + " bytes ***");

        //tell the sender OK to send data
        send(initPacket.getAddress(), initPacket.getPort(), ("OK").getBytes());

        fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        //two while loops. First checks that there is still more data to receive
        //and inner do/while is to error check on received packets and catch missing ACK
        //sent to sender
        while (bytesReceived < bytesToReceive)
        {
            receiveMSG = new Message();
            do
            {
                receivedPacket = receivePacket();
                try
                {
                    receiveMSG = (Message) deserialize(receivedPacket.getData());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("*** Message packet failed. ***");
                }

                //logically if the last ACK sent fails to be received the UDPSender will resend the last segment.
                //A simple check on the segemntID will catch this as it will be equal to expectedID - 1. Resending the ACK
                //for this previous segment will eventually get through to the server to send the next expected segment.
                if ((expectedSegmentID - 1) == receiveMSG.getSegmentID())
                {
                    String ACK = Integer.toString(receiveMSG.getSegmentID());
                    send(initPacket.getAddress(), initPacket.getPort(), (ACK).getBytes());
                    System.out.println("*** Resending ACK for segment " + ACK + " ***");
                }

                if (simulateMessageFail)
                {
                    simulateBadConnection = (Math.random() < 0.98) ? 0 : 1; //simulate a 2% chance a message object is lost
                }

                //by adding 1 to segmentIDExpected we can make the receiver determine a message object is lost
                //as the server has a 2 second timeout before it will resend we can check the error control in this way.
            } while (receiveMSG.getSegmentID() != (expectedSegmentID + simulateBadConnection));

            expectedSegmentID++;

            //handles the last byte segmentID size .getBytesToWrite()
            fileWriter.write(receiveMSG.getPacket(), 0, receiveMSG.getBytesToWrite());

            System.out.println("Received segmentID " + receiveMSG.getSegmentID());

            //adding payload size for outer while condition
            bytesReceived = bytesReceived + 512;

            //simulate a 2% chance an ACK is lost
            if (simulateMessageFail)
            {
                if ((Math.random() < 0.98))
                {
                    String ACK = Integer.toString(receiveMSG.getSegmentID());
                    send(initPacket.getAddress(), initPacket.getPort(), (ACK).getBytes());
                } else
                {
                    System.out.println("*** failed to send ACK ***");
                }
            } else
            {
                String ACK = Integer.toString(receiveMSG.getSegmentID());
                send(initPacket.getAddress(), initPacket.getPort(), (ACK).getBytes());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("*** File transfer complete. ***");
        fileWriter.close();
    }

    private DatagramPacket receivePacket() throws IOException
    {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        return packet;
    }

    private void send(InetAddress recv, int port, byte[] message) throws IOException
    {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, recv, port);
        socket.send(packet);
    }

    private Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteStream);
        return (Message) objectStream.readObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried compiling your code. It works fine for file size less than 512 bytes. For everything else I am getting [this](http://ideone.com/OYcGMq) exception. I am not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Use constants for PACKET_OVERHEAD and PREFERRED_TU (transmission unit, in memoriam MTU). Put them in the "size expression" instead of commenting it. @VelvetThunder bytesRead + packetOverhead a bit much for buffer, possibly.

Answer (score 3):

- You shouldn't do work in the constructor let alone ALL the work. You can move everything except `this.socket = socket;`
  from `UDPFileReceiver` constructor to a method `receive()`, like the `sendFile` method of `UDPFileSender`.
- There are unused fields, e.g. `buffer` from `CLIENTConnection`. You
  should heed compiler warnings.

Comment: Cheers. Point taken on the constructor. When one stares at the same code for so long basics slip past. I'll check on why I missed the missed buffer compiler warning too.

Comment: Thanks @abuzittin, I've changed my code as per your recommendations. I appreciate you took the time to check my code and point out the oversights.

Comment: I turned this answer into community wiki as it was not meant to be a comprehensive review at the time it was accepted. I want to see some review on the network protocol, as may people who find this question through search engines.

Comment: I wasn't sure about accepting actually, I just wanted to give credit where it was due. I can remove the accepted answer, let me know.

Comment: You can unaccept it.I was trying to get things rolling and keep the question active.